# Html embed on flex and open browser window from link

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, browser

Hi I have a html embed in my desktop application, then load a simple html page with simple links I want when the user click a link inside on my embed html page, the link launch the browser and open the html page.

Here is what I have so far:

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   backgroundColor="white"
                   minWidth="600" minHeight="450"
                   horizontalCenter="center">
<fx:Declarations>

    </fx:Declarations>



<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import flash.net.navigateToURL;

        import mx.managers.CursorManager;
                ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
<s:Group id="principal">


    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="0" paddingRight="0" paddingTop="0" paddingBottom="0"/>
    </s:layout>
            <s:Panel id="pantalla2" skinClass="skins.limpio" borderVisible="false" alpha="1" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:HTML id="content" location="https://misitio.com" paddingTop="0"  />

    </s:Panel>


            </s:Group>

          </s:Scroller>
       </s:WindowedApplication>
```

And my html:

```
<ul>

<li><strong>Páginas</strong></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="navigateToURL('http://google.com.mx',_blank)">google</a></li>
<li><a href="http://misitio.com/">sitio1.com</a></li>
<li><a href="http://misitio2.com/">sitio2.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Don't work, any ideas? Thanks in advance
Sorry my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will open all links in system browser

```
content.htmlLoader.navigateInSystemBrowser = true
```

Or if needed you can also try modifing only the links you want to include target="_blank" using some regex on the html code or by running a javascript function on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your html to the following

```
<li><a href="http://misitio.com/" target="_blank">sitio1.com</a></li>
```

But I wonder if it opens in a browser window. You have to try.

You can try [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cba.html) if you know which url the user is going to click.